# With custom view controller transitions, where do I get to hide the status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uipresentationcontroller

**Sample Project:** http://cl.ly/1C0N0E0f3n2P

I'm trying to create a custom transition to a view controller in iOS 8. I'm using a `UIPresentationController` as well as an `NSObject` subclass that implements `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`, basically following [this tutorial](http://dativestudios.com/blog/2014/06/29/presentation-controllers/).

I also want to hide the status bar when the view controller gets presented, but I don't know where in this paradigm I'm to do this.

Whenever I try to call methods on the `presentingViewController` in the `UIPresentationController` subclass, or using a key in the `NSObject` subclass, I always get a crash, making me believe I'm not supposed to be calling methods on these?

*Example from sample:*

```
class CustomPresentationController: UIPresentationController {
    override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
        // Following line causes crash
        (presentingViewController as ViewController).testFunction()        

        let darkOverlayView = UIView(frame: presentingViewController.view.bounds)
        darkOverlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)

        containerView.addSubview(darkOverlayView)
    }
}
```

So where exactly am I to hide the status bar? I don't want to call it at the same time that I call `presentViewController`, as every time that gets presented I want to hide the status bar, so it should be wrapped up in the animation itself, for DRY principles.

Comment: Can you please show the code from your actual attempt, and the stack trace from the crash?

Comment: I'll upload a sample, sec.

Comment: @AaronBrager Added the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will fix the crash.

```
let controller = presentingViewController as UINavigationController
let ctl = controller.topViewController as ViewController
ctl.testFunction()
```